# How to select a value from span class of a dropbox in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick form-control yearfield clsyearfiled open"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="Year" title="2022" aria-expanded="true"><span class="filter-option pull-left">2022</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button><div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 156px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 127px;"><div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" pwa2-uuid="EDITOR/input-35D-F49-8BE31-9C5" pwa-fake-editor=""></div><ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 113px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 84px;"><li data-original-index="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2022</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2023</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2024</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li><li data-original-index="3"><a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">2025</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li></ul></div><select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick yearfield clsyearfiled" id="Year" multiple="multiple" name="Year" data-live-search="true" data-dropup-auto="false" data-focus-off="true" style="text-transform: capitalize" title="Year" data-max-options="1" tabindex="-98"><option selected="selected" value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
<option value="2025">2025</option>
</select></div>
```

This is my code and I have been able to reach upto opening the dropbox but unable to select the value of 2023

```
year = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='2022'] span[class='filter-option pull-left']")
year.click()
year.select_by_index(1)
```

I have tried using select but it doesn't work on span class

Comment: Your `select` has `id="Year"`, which should be a more direct and easier to use reference!

Comment: Also note that `select` list elements need special treatment in Selinium: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/select_lists/

Comment: Well, I have tried using ID but it doesn't work hence went for css selector, it opened the dropbox

Comment: You need post the entire html or share the url, if it is public.

Answer (score 0):

`select_by_index` is a method of [Select](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) class. WebElement class instance doesn't have it. You need to use this code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 

year = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("Year"))
year.select_by_index(1)
```

Comment: This is the error which I have been getting since when I use select
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <span>

Comment: Where is `span[class='filter-option pull-left']` in your given `HTML` ??

Comment: @SteveKundukulangara did you try my **exact** code? `@id="Year"` is `select` node, not `span` and so you cannot get `UnexpectedTagNameException` error!